# html/css: set div bounding box to window height

Tags: html, css

It looks like I'm missing something basic.
I want a certain DIV to have the height of the window. The effect should be that there's never any need to scroll down.

Do I have to use JavaScript? I was told that it's possible with css, but I can't find the relevant property - or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the trick:

```
body { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  height:100%; /* this is the key! */ 
}

.yourDivStyle {
  ...
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this won't work. this will make the DIV the same size of the body if it the is a direct child of the body. remember that the html body is not the same height as the window. Javascript is the way to go here.

Comment: @Pablo, what is the solution then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn scrolling off, use this CSS:

```
html, body
{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

But remember now the content will not scroll - you can put overflow:auto or overflow:scroll on individual divs if you need some scrolling.

If you use Javascript make sure to register for the onresize event so that you can change numbers if the window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

Make all parents have `height: 100%;` or use `position: absolute /* or fixed */; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to use JavaScript? I was
>   told that it's possible with css, but
>   I can't find the relevant property -
>   or I'm doing something wrong.

Javascript is the way to go, you can not determine winodow size with css and and re-calculate based on window resizing.

Comment: Uh, he can if the dimension is based on percent, not px.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so in Javascript (not jQuery or anything):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

 var sWidth;
 var sHeight;


 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
 {
      sWidth = window.innerWidth,
      sHeight = window.innerHeight
 } else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
 {
       sWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
       sHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
 } else
 {
       sWidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
       sHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
 }
//VARIABLES STORED IN sWidth AND sHeight
document.write('<div style="height: '+sHeight+'; width: '+sWidth+';">CONTENT</div>');
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously you could write the div out seperately ^_^